# Как удалить диапазон элементов массива за log(n) час?

Tags: алгоритм

Кратко об условии задачи:

Дано числа от `1` до `n`, и `m` этапов очищения,после этого следует в m строках по два числа `left` и `right` (границы включительно) диапазон удаления чисел `(1..n)`, надо вывести все живые элементы после удаления.

Наведу пример:

```
n = 10, m = 3
```

Допустим мы сделаем массив `a[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`

```
left = 1, right = 2;
```

После 1 очищения: `a[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`

```
left = 4, right = 5;
```

После 2 очищения: `a[3,4,5,8,9,10];`

```
left = 3, right = 5;
```

После 3 очищения: `a[3,4,10];`

Вывод: `3 4 10`

Так не все так просто, ограничения строгие, а именно:

- `n,m <= 3*10^5`
- `left<=right`

Моя попытка была в следующем: создал вектор из чисел от 1 до n и удалял все элементы `a[left,right]`, но идёт `TimeLimit` из за сложности .

Был бы благодарен за объяснение решения данной задачи, или за код на C++.

Comment: Я бы дерево отрезков использовал.

Comment: Задача эта не на использование языка, а алгоритмическая, а Вы опять её не пометили меткой "алгоритм"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как решается такая задача. Вам нужен вектор пар left-right. И он должен  быть отсортирован и не перекрывающийся. Когда в этот векто добавляется новая пара, ищем бинарным поиском подходящее место по left. И потом либо просто вставляем пару в середину (если начало ее больше за конец предыдущей и конец меньше на начало следующей) или объединениям с одной или двумя, если участки перекрываются ( то есть, кол-во диапазонов может и уменьшиться).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82310/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-kovadim).

Comment: А можно какой нибудь псевдокод накидать?Спасибо.

Comment: Если честно,всегда у меня небольшие трудности с бинарным поиском.